# Twisted getpage using proxy

Tags: python, http, networking, proxy, twisted

I use `getpage ()` to load the pages:

```
 d = getPage(url)
 d.addCallback(parsePage,url)
 d.addErrback(downloadError,url)
```

Now you need to download via http proxy. How can I call `getpage ()` to use http proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`twisted.web.client.ProxyAgent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.ProxyAgent.html) instead.  `getPage` is Twisted's old, not-very-good HTTP client API.  [`IAgent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.iweb.IAgent.html) is the new, better HTTP client API.  Apart from its other advantages, it also has more features than `getPage` - including support for HTTP proxies.

Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from os import environ

from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint
from twisted.web.client import ProxyAgent

def main(reactor, proxy_hostname):
    endpoint = HostnameEndpoint(reactor, proxy_hostname, 80)
    agent = ProxyAgent(endpoint)
    return agent.request(b"GET", b"http://google.com/").addCallback(print)

react(main, [environ["HTTP_PROXY"]])
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a bit more detail to this answer?